# How to add data to jquery created element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Adding data to new element:

```
var ComBox = $('<div></div>').addClass('commentBox');
$.data(ComBox, 'ChannelID', 5);
$('body').append(ComBox);
```

When trying to get the data, results in undefined..

```
var cID = $('.commentBox').data('ChannelID');
console.log('cID : '+cID );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$.data(ComBox, 'ChannelID', 5);
```

With this:

```
ComBox.data('ChannelID', 5);
```

It uses [this function](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

Best practice note, you better prefix your jQuery object with $  meaning:
`ComBox` => `$comBox`

Answer (score 0):

[`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) expects a *DOM* element, not a *jQuery* object. Either use:

```
$.data(ComBox[0], 'ChannelID', 5);
```

Or the more convenient [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, as suggested by @gdoron:

```
ComBox.data('ChannelID', 5);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5pdx/)**.